# Почему не загружается вложенный шорткод?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, шорткод

Добавил на сайте вложенный шорткод.
Первый шорткод лайтбокса, а в него вложен шорткод фотографии с прокруткой 360 градусов. Лайтбокс открывается, но шорткод с фотографией не загружается. Причём, если открыть в браузере консоль разработчика или изменить масштаб страницы, то вложенный шорткод начинает отображаться.
Шорткод проверял на отображение текстовых полей и изображений, они загружались.

Код шорткодов:
[lightbox id="333" width="600px" padding="20px"][wc360 id="5847" width="400" height="600"][/lightbox]

Почему вложенный шорткод может не загружаться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что Lightbox не знает размеров этого изображения, вставленного в него по второму шорткоду. Когда вы делаете resize, скрипт лайтбокса отрабатывает изменения размеров и показывает картинку.

Задайте размер вставляемой по внутреннему шорткоду картинки через css, явно. Все будет работать при запуске лайтбокса.

Точнее ответить не могу без html кода этой конструкции.

Comment: Добавил в css высоту и ширину по 900px. Теперь лайтбокс открывается почти на всю страницу, но шорткод woocommerce всё равно не отображается сразу, хотя по размеру он намного меньше, чем лайтбокс.

Comment: Вы не туда добавили высоту:     .threesixty {
    height: 400px !important;
}

Comment: а с лайтбокса уберите 900 на 900, это не нужно. У вас класс threesixty высоты не имеет при старте

Comment: Спасибо! Всё заработало. Если бы не Вы, то я мог бы ещё несколько дней так просидеть с этой проблемой.

Comment: Просто сталкивался с таким на fancybox. Заходите еще с вопросами)